# what is com.apple.dock.agent?

Tags: macos, mac, dock

I would like to know some details about com.apple.dock.agent?

What is this process? is it so important? does it has anyhting to do with UI?

I would really appreciate if one can share as many details as they can regarding the dock agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're asking about the process that you see in the Console. It's associated with the [OS X Dock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_%28Mac_OS_X%29), so yes, it's a major component of the UI. Are there any specific details that you need? Google and [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2474) have a lot of links to Dock details. I'm not sure if you want technical or usage details - please provide more info.

Comment: Yes there are lot of details about dock. But nothing much about dock.agent. I am trying to figure out what are the duties/job associated with this dock.agent. Doing so will allow me to understand how it makes use of OpenGL to create such animations and effects.

Comment: FYI, my OSX 10.8 machine has a Dock extras as well, but it does not seem to be related to this; http://apple.wikia.com/wiki/Dock_Extra . My purpose in looking at these things is to slim down my mac - activity monitor shows a process for com.apple.dock.extra in addition to Dock.